# monaca inmobi ads blank

Tags: inmobi, monaca

i  have signed up  at inmobi,have made a banner ad and tried my  best to get it working to no  avail,seems like the  ad div appears,but not the ad itself
 here is  my  code.as yoU CAN see my property id  provided by inmobi for ad has been entered.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <script src="js/cssua.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/inmobi.js"></script>
    <script>
        var inmobi_conf = {
            siteid : "48a58302dd214f5ea5483a3f9d95a28e", // your Property ID
            slot: 15,
            test: true,
            manual: true,
            autoRefresh: 20,
            targetWindow : "_top", // default "_top"
            onError : function(code){
                if(code == "nfr"){
                    console.log("Error getting the ads!");
                }
                  if(code!=="nfr"){
                    console.log("getting the ads!");
                }
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady(){
            console.log('device is ready');
            showAds();
        }

        function showAds(){
            var adsElement = document.getElementById('ads');
            _inmobi.getNewAd(adsElement);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body> 
    <div data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
          <h1>Inmobi Client</h1>
        </header>
        <div data-role="content">
            <img src="images/logo.png" width="300px">
        </div>
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> 
            <div id="ads"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```